# Tengo el siguiente error. ¿Alguien sabe cuál es el problema?

Tags: nodejs, npm, babeljs, gulp-sass, nvm

> jm-boilerplate@1.0.0 start /home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web
>    gulp
>
> [14:30:36] Requiring external module @babel/register
>   /home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178
>       throw new Error(`Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In ${filepath}`);
>       ^
>
> Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only
>   functions. In
>   /home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js
>       at createDescriptor (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
>       at items.map (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at createDescriptors (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
>       at createPresetDescriptors (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
>       at presets (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
>       at mergeChainOpts (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
>       at /home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
>       at buildRootChain (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:120:22)
>       at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:85:55)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
>   jm-boilerplate@1.0.0 start: `gulp` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the jm-boilerplate@1.0.0 start script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/frank/.npm/_logs/2019-12-23T19_30_36_678Z-debug.log

Comment: Tu pregunta debe formularse en español. Tradúcela y explica en qué contexto obtienes el error. Editando la pregunta.

Comment: Estimado, por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y reformula esto, dado que las preguntas solo con el error son mal vistas, faltan el cómo ocurrio, el donde ocurrió, cual es el resultado esperado, entre otros.

Comment: Agrega y explica lo que estas realizando, saludos!

Comment: Estoy tratando de levantar un project usando: npm run start, donde mi packet.json en el script start: 'gulp'

Answer (score -1):

> > jm-boilerplate@1.0.0 start /home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web
> >     gulp
>
> [23:26:34] Requiring external module @babel/register
>   /home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178
>       throw new Error(`Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In ${filepath}`);
>       ^
>
> Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only
>   functions. In
>   /home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js
>       at createDescriptor (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
>       at items.map (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at createDescriptors (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
>       at createPresetDescriptors (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
>       at presets (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
>       at mergeChainOpts (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
>       at /home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
>       at buildRootChain (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:120:22)
>       at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/home/frank/Globall66-Projects/Growth-Projects/g66-web/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:85:55)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
>   jm-boilerplate@1.0.0 start: `gulp` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the jm-boilerplate@1.0.0 start script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/frank/.npm/_logs/2019-12-24T04_26_34_620Z-debug.log